# Get the instances recommendations from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to get the recommendations for mi instances, such as "Over-provisioned", etc

But I don't get the right syntax for the following command:

```
$ aws export-ec2-instance-recommendations --filters name=RecommendationSourceType,values=Ec2Instance
```

Could anyone help me with a little example of the input and outoput?

Comment: aws compute-optimizer get-ec2-instance-recommendations --filters name=RecommendationSourceType,values=Ec2Instance This will display it on CLI, if you want to export you will need to use the aws compute-optimizer export-ec2-instance-recommendations command

Comment: question says get and example commands uses export? little unclear
for reference https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/compute-optimizer/get-ec2-instance-recommendations.html